# How to redirect from one page to another page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not getting how to do this codeignitor concept.
How to redirect one page to another page if I click the link?

Main1.php

```
        <?php 

            class Main1 extends CI_Controller { 

                public function index() { 
                    //Load the URL helper
                    $this->load->helper('url'); 

                    //Redirect the user to some site
                    redirect('http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/Main'); 

                   $this->load->view('test1'); 
                } 
            } 
        ?>
```

test1.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> Without Extension </h1>
                <a href="">Visit With Extension Example</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Main.php

```
    <?php 

        class Main extends CI_Controller { 

            public function index() { 
                $this->load->view('test.html'); 
            } 
        } 
    ?>
```

test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> With Extension </h1>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I really hope for you you don't have any spaces before your opening tags in your real php code, otherwise the redirect won't work because content has already been sent.

Comment: You should just call another controller from your view if you want to open another Controller

Comment: how to do that sir im really a begginer to this topic please can u guide me please how to do this?

Comment: My first question for you: Do you understand the MVC concept already?

Comment: yes sir i have understood it

Comment: Avoid calling controllers within a controller as a normal practice since you are new to Codeigniter. You should always conform to the coding standards of the framework. If you become used to this practice, you'll be encountering more problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `redirect();`  something like given below.

```
redirect('controllerName/methodName','refresh');
```

OR 
if you want to redirect in same controller.

```
$this->methondName;
```

Your code should be like this

```
 <?php 

    class Main1 extends CI_Controller { 

        public function index() { 
            //Load the URL helper
            $this->load->helper('url'); 

            //Redirect the user to some site
            redirect('Main/index','refresh'); 

        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: please check my code sir, actually what im doing is trying to redirect from test1.php to test.html or vice versa

Comment: ping me by clicking given link

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to redirect from Controller `Main1` to `Main`. Main1 loads the test1.php view, and it should contain a means to redirect from one view to another, like a button or a link. You should have a `.php` extension instead of `.html` to utilize php. Consider this as a best practice and you should avoid calling controllers within a controller as a normal practice to conform with MVC in general.

Test1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> With Extension </h1>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url("Main/"); ?>">Visit With Extension Example</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If you call `Main` then the controller will be processed. No need for you to use redirect inside the controller.

```
<?php 

class Main extends CI_Controller { 
    public function index() {
       $this->load->view('test'); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Main1.php index function , loading view after redirecting. It is not possible.

**Main1.php**

```
            class Main1 extends CI_Controller { 

                public function index() { 
                    //Load the URL helper
                    $this->load->helper('url'); 

//display test1 page
                   $this->load->view('test1'); 
                } 
            } 
        ?>
```

**test1.php**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> Without Extension </h1>
                <a href="http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/Main">Visit With Extension Example</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Main.php**

load->view('test.html'); 
        } 
    } 
?>

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>view page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
            <h1 style="color:red"> With Extension </h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

*It is a small error..keep going with codeigniter*

Comment: sir this will work i tried but i need to do it with the help of codeignitor functionality

Comment: what kind of functionality? this is basic codeigniter functionality, or you just go through with base_url , routes etc...

Comment: This is what i need to use sir i did but its not working please can u guide me how to use this

Comment: please set base_url in codeigniter project_folder/application/config/config.php file & routes in project_folder/application/config/routes .php file , avoid using index.php  in url (search htaccess in codeigniter to avoid index.php from url)

Comment: how to do that sir i tried what u said but not getting result

Comment: i tried this but its not working <a href="<?php echo site_url('main/index');?>">Visit With Extension Example</a>

Comment: <?php echo base_url(); echo site_url('main/index'); ?> please provide two out this two echo outputs

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

`redirect('controllerName/methodName','refresh');` in your controller or if you want to just load the previous page you can use `redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Comment: If I use redirect function n later in my browser when I reload the page it's showing that page which I want to be displayed when actually I click link but instead after reloading it's showing that page only