# Unable to redirect from one page to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Main1.php

```
        <?php 

            class Main1 extends CI_Controller { 

                public function index() { 
                    //Load the URL helper
                    $this->load->helper('url'); 

                    //Redirect the user to some site
                    redirect('http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/Main'); 

                   $this->load->view('test1'); 
                } 
            } 
        ?>
```

test1.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> Without Extension </h1>
                <a href="">Visit With Extension Example</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Main.php

```
    <?php 

        class Main extends CI_Controller { 

            public function index() { 
                $this->load->view('test.html'); 
            } 
        } 
    ?>
```

test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red"> With Extension </h1>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm purely new to this codeignitor concept, i know its really a stupid question, but please guys try t help me .Actually when i click the link im trying to redirect one page to another page and vice versa using codeignitor functions , but im unable to do this please can any one tel me where im going wrong,sorry i know its really stupid question but not getting how to do.

Comment: Found duplicate ***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943206/how-to-redirect-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-codeignitor***

Comment: I've already posted the answer in your previous question. I don't know why you don't want to conform to the standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect from one page to another page in codeignitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943206/how-to-redirect-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-codeignitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a **link** that moves you from one page to another the `redirect()` function is not the answer. A "redirect" is effectively the same as typing a new URL in a browser - only it is done programmatically.

The `<a>` HTML tag is used to create a link to another URL in the user interface.

Here are revised files that will do what you want.
Note that the `redirect()` call has been removed.

**/controllers/Main.php**

```
<?php

class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Load the URL helper
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('test.html');
    }
}
```

Please note that there is no PHP closing tag ie. `?>` at the end of the file. As stated in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.

**/views/test.html** is the view file loaded by the controller above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>view page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
                <h1 style="color:red">HTML file view</h1>
                <a href='<?= base_url('main1');?>'>View using php extension</a>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here are the other pair of files for loading a php view file.

**/controllers/Main1.php**

```
<?php
class Main1 extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('test1');
    }
}
```

**/views/test1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>view page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-top:50px; padding-left:300px">
        <h1 style="color:red">PHP view file</h1>
        <a href='<?= base_url('main');?>'>View using html Extension</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

FWIW, there is no advantage in using .html files for your views, but there is a disadvantage. The problem will be that sometimes you will need to execute a little PHP in a view which means it must use .php for the extension. Soon you are trying to juggle a mix of .html and .php view files and before you know it you're confused and angry that things aren't working the way you expected. Make life easier and stick to .php for view files - even if there isn't any PHP code in the file.

Comment: sir i have one more doubt please can u help me to solve that

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088024/how-to-call-a-section-of-one-view-page-in-to-another-view-page

Comment: please visit this link sir, i want to get this work done desperately, im trying it from yesterday but its not getting completed

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: I'm looking at it now.

Comment: ok sir thank you please let me know if u get any answer for that question

Comment: sir did you got any answer

Comment: My friend, give me some time to answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `redirect` with your destination path (controller/method [*if **index**, controller name is enough*] )

```
redirect('main');
```

You can use `redirect` with these scenarios

1. Controller redirect (automatically call `index` function)
2. Controller method redirect (main/test)
3. route redirect (`main-test` where main-test pointed to the specific method)

---

**FYI :
once `redirect` function reached, any code below that won't get executed**

Comment: Exactly sir this is what im facing promble, i mean to say i have a page in that page i have a link so if i click that link then it should redirect to another page, but if i use redirect function then the page which is to be displyed after clicking the link na , it is displayed before i click the link

Comment: once redirect function reached, any code below that won't get executed,this one is correct sir

Comment: so now how to redirect it sir using codeignitor functions ?

Comment: you cant to show  `test1` contents in redirected page ??

Comment: then add test1 in redirected function. `$this->load->view('test1'); $this->load->view('test.html');`

Comment: not getting u sir, Actually wht im trying to do is that, their is link in test 1.php file so when i click that link it should redirect to the test.html file or vice versa like this im trying to do sir but i don know where im going wrong

Comment: Wait. Calm down and take a good breath. and clearly explain to me what you want to do

Comment: im doing a task on redirecting one page to another page using pure codeignitor functions, so i have one link in test1.php so when i click that link na it should direct to test.html,

Comment: **when i click that link** show me this line of code

Comment: sorry sir m not getting u, can u see my code which i have pasted

Comment: when you click `<a href="">Visit With Extension Example</a>` you need to load `test.html` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` if you wants redirect external link of any page