# how to call a section of one view page in to another view page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

how can i  display only "Welcome to my 3rd Blog!" of "blogvieww.php" in 
"blogview.php" using codegniter. But the below code what i tried with is that, even "Welcome to my 2nd Blog!" of "blogvieww.php" is getting displayed in "blogview.php".
actually i just want to display only  "Welcome to my 3rd Blog!", how to do this can any one tel me please im not getting where im going wrong.

Blogcontroller.php(controller file)

```
    <?php  
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

        class Blogcontroller extends CI_Controller {  

            public function index()  
            {  
                $data['blogvieww'] = $this->load->view('blogvieww', '', TRUE);
                $this->load->view('blogview', $data);  
            }  

            public function blogvieww()  
            {  
                $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
            } 
        }  
    ?>
```

blogview.php (view file)

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><?php echo $blogvieww; ?></div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

blogvieww.php (view file)

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>My Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 2nd Blog!</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my 3rd Blog!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please some one help me im not getting where im going wrong

Comment: simple way you can do simply by adding a `variable` in your controller and echoing that `variable` in `view`

Comment: sir i tried but its not working, please sir can u edit and tel me in my code please sir

Comment: i need to display only welcome to blog 3!, but even  welcome to blog 2 is also coming please can u edit my code n tel me sir please